# Custom Table with Auto-Scaling Text

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm attempting to make a table where the text "fills" the available cell, maximizing the font. I'm running these problems:

(1) When making the window smaller, the text's font size won't decrease smoothly with the resize.

(2) Because the font isn't resized correctly, clipping occurs (mostly on the left and right ends of the text)

Text sizing occurs in scale_text(), which is based off this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40883916/3047847). Is this issue occurring because of how the horizontal/vertical factoring is handled? I don't know why the text becomes massive all of a sudden, even though the point size of the font isn't any different from those around it.

Pictures and MRE Below:

[image: Issue1] [image: Issue2][image: Issue3]

MRE:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TestTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setRowCount(8)

        self.header_horizontal = TestHeader(self, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.header_vertical = TestHeader(self, QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

        self.setHorizontalHeader(self.header_horizontal)
        self.setVerticalHeader(self.header_vertical)

        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font.setPointSize(10)
        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)

        self.auto_size = 0

        self.align_left = QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft
        self.align_center = QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
        self.align_right = QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight

    def widget_at_pos(self, row, column):   # gets widget at (row,col)
        if not 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
            return None
        if not 0 <= column < self.columnCount():
            return None

        cell = self.cellWidget(row, column)
        if cell is None:
            cell = self.item(row, column)
        return cell

    def set_header_labels(self, labels, direction="horizontal"):    # sets headers
        if not isinstance(labels, list):
            return

        if direction == "horizontal":
            self.setColumnCount(len(labels))
        elif direction == "vertical":
            self.setRowCount(len(labels))
        else:
            return

        i = 0
        for label in labels:
            self.set_header_label(i, label, direction)
            i += 1

    def set_header_label(self, index, label, direction="horizontal"):
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText(label)
        if direction == "horizontal":
            self.setHorizontalHeaderItem(index, item)
        elif direction == "vertical":
            self.setVerticalHeaderItem(index, item)
        else:
            return

    def set_box_column(self, column=0, fmt="text", default=-1): # adds boxes in one column
        items = list()
        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            item = self.set_box(default, fmt, row, column)
            items.append(item)
        return items

    def set_box(self, value=None, fmt="text", row=0, column=0):
        if fmt == "text":
            box = SizedLineEdit(self)
            box.setText(value)
        elif fmt == "number":
            box = SizedSpinBox(self)
            box.setValue(value)
        else:
            return None

        box.setFont(self.font)
        self.setCellWidget(row, column, box)
        return box

    def clamp_font_table(self):     # clamps each row to their minimum font
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.clamp_font_row(i)

    def clamp_font_row(self, row):  # Sets widgets in row to smallest font
        min_font = 0

        for i in range(self.columnCount()): # find min font
            cell = self.widget_at_pos(row, i)
            if cell is None:
                continue
            if not isinstance(cell, (SizedSpinBox, SizedLineEdit)):
                continue
            if i == 0:
                min_font = cell.getFont().pointSize()
                continue
            min_font = min(min_font, cell.getFont().pointSize())

        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            cell = self.widget_at_pos(row, i)
            if not isinstance(cell, (SizedSpinBox, SizedLineEdit)):
                continue
            cell.setFont(size=min_font)

    def scale_text_table(self):     # resize contents of cells to fit the space
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                self.scale_text_cell(i, j)
            self.clamp_font_row(i)

    def scale_text_cell(self, row, column): # resize contents of cell to fit the space
        cell = self.widget_at_pos(row, column)
        if cell is None:
            return
        if isinstance(cell, (SizedSpinBox, SizedLineEdit)):
            cell.scale_text()

    def scale_to_data(self):    # adjusts column spacing to account for cell contents
        horizontal_header = self.horizontalHeader()
        vertical_header = self.verticalHeader()
        if not isinstance(horizontal_header, QtGui.QHeaderView):
            return
        if not isinstance(vertical_header, QtGui.QHeaderView):
            return

        horizontal_header.scale_to_data()
        vertical_header.scale_to_data()

        if self.auto_size == 1:
            horizontal_header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)
            horizontal_header.setStretchLastSection(True)
            if self.rowCount() > 1:
                vertical_header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
                vertical_header.setStretchLastSection(True)
        else:
            horizontal_header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
            horizontal_header.setStretchLastSection(True)

            vertical_header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
            vertical_header.setStretchLastSection(True)

        TestTable.resizeEvent(self, QtGui.QResizeEvent(self.size(), QtCore.QSize()))

    def resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.scale_text_table()
        self.clamp_font_table()
        QtGui.QTableWidget.resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)

class TestHeader(QtGui.QHeaderView):

    def __init__(self, parent, orientation=QtCore.Qt.Horizontal):
        QtGui.QHeaderView.__init__(self, orientation, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)

    def scale_to_data(self): # resize header to fit the content of its items
        for i in range(self.count()):
            width = self.sectionSize(i) # save current section width
            self.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents) # resize cell
            width = max(width, self.sectionSize(i)) # compare sizes
            self.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)
            self.resizeSection(i, width)

class SizedLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, text="sizedlineedit", *args):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = unicode(text)
        self.setReadOnly(True)

        self.minimum_characters = 1
        self.min_text_size = 8
        self.max_text_size = 300

        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
        self.setMinimumHeight(self.font.pointSize() * 1.1)
        self.setFont(self.font)

        self.setText(self.value)
        self.scale_text()

    def setFont(self, font=None, size=8):
        if isinstance(font, QtGui.QFont):
            self.font = font
        size = int(size)
        self.font.setPointSize(size)

        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
        QtGui.QLineEdit.setFont(self, self.font)

    def getFont(self):
        return self.font

    def setText(self, text):
        self.value = text
        QtGui.QLineEdit.setText(self, text)
        self.scale_text()

    def get_minimum_width(self):
        width = self.font_metrics.width(self.text())
        s = "0" * self.minimum_characters
        min_calc_width = self.font_metrics.width(s)
        return max(width, min_calc_width)

    def scale_text(self):   # resize text to fit in the cell
        h_factor = 1
        v_factor = 1

        r_width = float(self.rect().width())
        t_width = float(self.get_minimum_width())

        r_height = float(self.rect().height())
        t_height = float(self.font_metrics.height())

        if r_width > 0 and t_width > 0:
            h_factor = r_width / t_width

        if r_height > 0 and t_height > 0:
            v_factor = r_height / t_height

        factor = min(h_factor, v_factor)

        if factor < 1 or factor > 1.3:
            new_size = int(self.font.pointSize() * factor)
            if new_size % 2 != 0:
                new_size -= 1
            new_size = max(new_size, self.min_text_size)
            new_size = min(new_size, self.max_text_size)
            # print new_size
            self.setFont(size=new_size)

    def resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.scale_text()   # call twice to avoid wacky sizing
        self.scale_text()

class SizedSpinBox(QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setReadOnly(True)

        self.min_text_size = 8
        self.max_text_size = 300

        self.min = float("-inf")
        self.max = float("inf")

        self.leading = 0

        # regex validation
        float_regex = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9-.]*")
        float_regex.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(float_regex, self)

        # size policy
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        # alignment
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # font
        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
        self.setMinimumHeight(self.font.pointSize() * 1.1)
        self.setFont(self.font)

        self.line_edit = self.findChild(QtGui.QLineEdit)
        self.line_edit.installEventFilter(self)

        self.setValue(-1)
        self.setDecimals(3)
        self.scale_text()

    def setFont(self, font=None, size=8):
        if isinstance(font, QtGui.QFont):
            self.font = font
        size = int(size)
        self.font.setPointSize(size)

        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
        QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.setFont(self, self.font)

    def getFont(self):
        return self.font

    def setValue(self, value):
        QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.setValue(self, value)
        self.scale_text()

    def get_minimum_width(self):
        s = "0" * (self.leading + self.decimals() + 1)
        width = self.font_metrics.width(self.text())
        calc_width = self.font_metrics.width(s)
        return max(width, calc_width)

    def scale_text(self):   # resize text to fit within space
        h_factor = 1
        v_factor = 1

        r_width = float(self.rect().width())
        t_width = float(self.get_minimum_width())

        r_height = float(self.rect().height())
        t_height = float(self.font_metrics.height())

        if r_width > 0 and t_width > 0:
            h_factor = r_width / t_width

        if r_height > 0 and t_height > 0:
            v_factor = r_height / t_height

        factor = min(h_factor, v_factor)

        if factor < 1 or factor > 1.3:
            new_size = int(self.font.pointSize() * factor)
            if new_size % 2 != 0:
                new_size -= 1
            new_size = max(new_size, self.min_text_size)
            new_size = min(new_size, self.max_text_size)
            # print new_size
            self.setFont(size=new_size)

    def resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.scale_text()
        self.scale_text()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tbl = TestTable()

    columns = [u"Column 1", u"Column 2", u"Column 3", u"Column 4"]
    rows = [u"Row 1", u"Row 2", u"Row 3", u"Row 4", u"Row 5", u"Row 6"]

    tbl.set_header_labels(columns, "horizontal")
    tbl.set_header_labels(rows, "vertical")

    tbl.set_box_column(0, "text", "False")
    tbl.set_box_column(1, "number", -1)
    tbl.set_box_column(2, "text", "True")
    tbl.set_box_column(3, "number", 1)

    tbl.show()
    tbl.scale_to_data()
    app.exec_()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. The updated MRE is included at the end.

There are the changes I made to the code above:

(1) Changed how width was calculated.

```
def get_minimum_width(self):   # calculates width using min_font_size
    width = self.min_font_metrics.width(self.text())
    s = "0" * (self.leading + self.decimals() + 1)
    min_calc_width = self.min_font_metrics.width(s)
    return max(width, min_calc_width)

def get_width(self):   # calculates width using current font size
    width = self.font_metrics.width(self.text())
    s = "0" * (self.leading + self.decimals() + 1)
    calc_width = self.font_metrics.width(s)
    return max(width, calc_width)
```

(2) Set minimum size hints when setting text. This will set the minimum size of the LineEdit to be the size of the text at the minimum allowed text size.

```
def setValue(self, value):
    QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.setValue(self, value)
    self.setMinimumWidth(self.get_minimum_width()) # added line
    self.scale_text()
```

(3) Calculated the maximum possible font size per resize. When clipping, the text would set itself to the maximum allowed font, which was 300. If we calculate the maximum font size according to the size of the box, we can set the max to be 45 (random size) rather than 300.

```
def setFont(self, font=None, size=8):
    if isinstance(font, QtGui.QFont):
        self.font = font

    size = int(size)
    size = max(size, self.min_text_size)
    size = min(size, self.calculate_max_font()) # clamps fonts with updating size
    self.font.setPointSize(size)

    self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
    QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.setFont(self, self.font)

def calculate_max_font(self, lower=8, upper=300): # O(logn) alg to calculate maximum possible font
    mid = lower + ((upper - lower) // 2)
    mid_font = QtGui.QFont()
    mid_font.setPointSize(mid)
    metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(mid_font)

    v_factor = 1
    h_factor = 1

    r_width = float(self.rect().width())
    t_width = float(metrics.width(self.text()))

    r_height = float(self.rect().height())
    t_height = float(metrics.height())

    if r_width > 0 and t_width > 0:
        h_factor = r_width / t_width

    if r_height > 0 and t_height > 0:
        v_factor = r_height / t_height

    if v_factor > 1.2 and h_factor > 1.3:
        return self.calculate_fit(mid, upper)
    elif v_factor < 1 and h_factor < 1:
        return self.calculate_fit(lower, mid)

    factor = min(h_factor, v_factor)

    if factor < 1 or factor > 1.3:
        new_size = int(mid * factor)
        if new_size % 2 != 0:
            new_size -= 1
        return new_size

    return mid
```

(4) Added catching of clipped text in scale_text. rect() is the widget's bounding rectangle. If the text exceeds that boundary, something went wrong in setting the font.

```
def scale_text(self):  # resize text to fit within space
    h_factor = 1
    v_factor = 1

    r_width = float(self.rect().width())
    t_width = float(self.get_width())

    r_height = float(self.rect().height())
    t_height = float(self.font_metrics.height())

    if t_width > r_width and t_height > r_height: # added
        self.setFont(size=self.min_text_size)
        return

    if r_width > 0 and t_width > 0:
        h_factor = r_width / t_width

    if r_height > 0 and t_height > 0:
        v_factor = r_height / t_height

    factor = min(h_factor, v_factor)

    if factor < 1 or factor > 1.3:
        new_size = int(self.font.pointSize() * factor)
        if new_size % 2 != 0:
            new_size -= 1
        self.setFont(size=new_size)
```

(5) Decreased the number of resizing calls, specifically the calls made in the table's resize event handler.

```
def resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
    QtGui.QTableWidget.resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.clamp_font_table()
```

There are still some bugs I encounter, but for the most part, this should be pretty clean.

Updated MRE:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TestTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setRowCount(8)

        self.header_horizontal = TestHeader(self, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.header_vertical = TestHeader(self, QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

        self.setHorizontalHeader(self.header_horizontal)
        self.setVerticalHeader(self.header_vertical)

        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font.setPointSize(10)
        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)

        self.auto_size = 0

        self.align_left = QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft
        self.align_center = QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
        self.align_right = QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def widget_at_pos(self, row, column):   # gets widget at (row,col)
        if not 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
            return None
        if not 0 <= column < self.columnCount():
            return None

        cell = self.cellWidget(row, column)
        if cell is None:
            cell = self.item(row, column)
        return cell

    def set_header_labels(self, labels, direction="horizontal"):    # sets headers
        if not isinstance(labels, list):
            return

        if direction == "horizontal":
            self.setColumnCount(len(labels))
        elif direction == "vertical":
            self.setRowCount(len(labels))
        else:
            return

        i = 0
        for label in labels:
            self.set_header_label(i, label, direction)
            i += 1

    def set_header_label(self, index, label, direction="horizontal"):
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setText(label)
        if direction == "horizontal":
            self.setHorizontalHeaderItem(index, item)
        elif direction == "vertical":
            self.setVerticalHeaderItem(index, item)
        else:
            return

    def set_box_column(self, column=0, fmt="text", default=-1): # adds boxes in one column
        items = list()
        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            item = self.set_box(default, fmt, row, column)
            items.append(item)
        return items

    def set_box(self, value=None, fmt="text", row=0, column=0):
        if fmt == "text":
            box = SizedLineEdit(self)
            box.setText(value)
        elif fmt == "number":
            box = SizedSpinBox(self)
            box.setValue(value)
        else:
            return None

        box.setFont(self.font)
        self.setCellWidget(row, column, box)
        return box

    def clamp_font_table(self):     # clamps each row to their minimum font
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.clamp_font_row(i)

    def clamp_font_row(self, row):  # Sets widgets in row to smallest font
        min_font = 0

        for i in range(self.columnCount()): # find min font
            cell = self.widget_at_pos(row, i)
            if cell is None:
                continue
            if not isinstance(cell, (SizedSpinBox, SizedLineEdit)):
                continue
            if i == 0:
                min_font = cell.getFont().pointSize()
                continue
            min_font = min(min_font, cell.getFont().pointSize())

        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            cell = self.widget_at_pos(row, i)
            if not isinstance(cell, (SizedSpinBox, SizedLineEdit)):
                continue
            cell.setFont(size=min_font)

    def scale_text_table(self):     # resize contents of cells to fit the space
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                self.scale_text_cell(i, j)
            self.clamp_font_row(i)

    def scale_text_cell(self, row, column): # resize contents of cell to fit the space
        cell = self.widget_at_pos(row, column)
        if cell is None:
            return
        if isinstance(cell, (SizedSpinBox, SizedLineEdit)):
            cell.scale_text()

    def scale_to_data(self):    # adjusts column spacing to account for cell contents
        horizontal_header = self.horizontalHeader()
        vertical_header = self.verticalHeader()
        if not isinstance(horizontal_header, QtGui.QHeaderView):
            return
        if not isinstance(vertical_header, QtGui.QHeaderView):
            return

        TestTable.resizeEvent(self, QtGui.QResizeEvent(self.size(), QtCore.QSize()))

        horizontal_header.scale_to_data()
        vertical_header.scale_to_data()

        if self.auto_size == 1:
            horizontal_header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)
            horizontal_header.setStretchLastSection(True)
            if self.rowCount() > 1:
                vertical_header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
                vertical_header.setStretchLastSection(True)
        else:
            horizontal_header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
            horizontal_header.setStretchLastSection(True)

            vertical_header.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
            vertical_header.setStretchLastSection(True)

    def resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.clamp_font_table()

class TestHeader(QtGui.QHeaderView):

    def __init__(self, parent, orientation=QtCore.Qt.Horizontal):
        QtGui.QHeaderView.__init__(self, orientation, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)

    def scale_to_data(self): # resize header to fit the content of its items
        for i in range(self.count()):
            width = self.sectionSize(i) # save current section width
            self.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents) # resize cell
            width = max(width, self.sectionSize(i)) # compare sizes
            self.setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Interactive)
            self.resizeSection(i, width)

class SizedLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, text="sizedlineedit", *args):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = unicode(text)
        self.setReadOnly(True)

        self.minimum_characters = 1
        self.min_text_size = 8

        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font.setPointSize(self.min_text_size)
        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
        self.setMinimumHeight(self.font.pointSize() * 1.1)
        self.setMaximumHeight(self.max_text_size * 1.1)
        self.setFont(self.font)

        min_font = QtGui.QFont()
        min_font.setPointSize(self.min_text_size)
        self.min_font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(min_font)

        self.setText(self.value)
        self.scale_text()

    def setFont(self, font=None, size=8):
        if isinstance(font, QtGui.QFont):
            self.font = font

        size = int(size)
        size = max(size, self.min_text_size)
        size = min(size, self.calculate_max_font())
        self.font.setPointSize(size)
        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
        QtGui.QLineEdit.setFont(self, self.font)

    def getFont(self):
        return self.font

    def setText(self, text):
        self.value = text
        QtGui.QLineEdit.setText(self, text)
        self.setMinimumWidth(self.get_minimum_width())
        self.scale_text()

    def get_minimum_width(self):
        width = self.min_font_metrics.width(self.text())
        s = "0" * self.minimum_characters
        min_calc_width = self.min_font_metrics.width(s)
        return max(width, min_calc_width)

    def get_width(self):
        width = self.font_metrics.width(self.text())
        s = "0" * self.minimum_characters
        min_calc_width = self.font_metrics.width(s)
        return max(width, min_calc_width)

    def calculate_max_font(self, lower=8, upper=300):
        mid = lower + ((upper - lower) // 2)
        mid_font = QtGui.QFont()
        mid_font.setPointSize(mid)
        metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(mid_font)

        v_factor = 1
        h_factor = 1

        r_width = float(self.rect().width())
        t_width = float(metrics.width(self.text()))

        r_height = float(self.rect().height())
        t_height = float(metrics.height())

        if r_width > 0 and t_width > 0:
            h_factor = r_width / t_width

        if r_height > 0 and t_height > 0:
            v_factor = r_height / t_height

        if v_factor > 1.2 and h_factor > 1.2:
            return self.calculate_fit(mid, upper)
        elif v_factor < 1 and h_factor < 1:
            return self.calculate_fit(lower, mid)

        factor = min(h_factor, v_factor)

        if factor < 1 or factor > 1.2:
            new_size = int(mid * factor)
            if new_size % 2 != 0:
                new_size -= 1
            return new_size

        return upper

    # def scale_text(self):
    #     self.setFont(size=self.calculate_fit())

    def scale_text(self):  # resize text to fit within space
        h_factor = 1
        v_factor = 1

        r_width = float(self.rect().width())
        t_width = float(self.get_width())

        r_height = float(self.rect().height())
        t_height = float(self.font_metrics.height())

        if t_width > r_width and t_height > r_height:
            self.setFont(size=self.min_text_size)
            return

        if r_width > 0 and t_width > 0:
            h_factor = r_width / t_width

        if r_height > 0 and t_height > 0:
            v_factor = r_height / t_height

        factor = min(h_factor, v_factor)

        if factor < 1 or factor > 1.3:
            new_size = int(self.font.pointSize() * factor)
            if new_size % 2 != 0:
                new_size -= 1
            self.setFont(size=new_size)

    def resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.scale_text()

class SizedSpinBox(QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setReadOnly(True)

        self.min_text_size = 8

        self.min = float("-inf")
        self.max = float("inf")

        self.leading = 0

        # regex validation
        float_regex = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9-.]*")
        float_regex.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(float_regex, self)

        # size policy
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        # alignment
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        # font
        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font.setPointSize(self.min_text_size)
        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
        self.setMinimumHeight(self.font.pointSize() * 1.1)
        self.setMaximumHeight(self.max_text_size * 1.1)
        self.setFont(self.font)

        min_font = QtGui.QFont()
        min_font.setPointSize(self.min_text_size)
        self.min_font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(min_font)

        self.line_edit = self.findChild(QtGui.QLineEdit)
        self.line_edit.installEventFilter(self)

        self.setValue(-1)
        self.setDecimals(3)
        self.scale_text()

    def setFont(self, font=None, size=8):
        if isinstance(font, QtGui.QFont):
            self.font = font

        size = int(size)
        size = max(size, self.min_text_size)
        size = min(size, self.calculate_max_font())
        self.font.setPointSize(size)

        self.font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
        QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.setFont(self, self.font)

    def getFont(self):
        return self.font

    def setValue(self, value):
        QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.setValue(self, value)
        self.setMinimumWidth(self.get_minimum_width())
        self.scale_text()

    def get_minimum_width(self):
        width = self.min_font_metrics.width(self.text())
        s = "0" * (self.leading + self.decimals() + 1)
        min_calc_width = self.min_font_metrics.width(s)
        return max(width, min_calc_width)

    def get_width(self):
        width = self.font_metrics.width(self.text())
        s = "0" * (self.leading + self.decimals() + 1)
        min_calc_width = self.font_metrics.width(s)
        return max(width, min_calc_width)

    def calculate_max_font(self, lower=8, upper=300):
        mid = lower + ((upper - lower) // 2)
        mid_font = QtGui.QFont()
        mid_font.setPointSize(mid)
        metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(mid_font)

        v_factor = 1
        h_factor = 1

        r_width = float(self.rect().width())
        t_width = float(metrics.width(self.text()))

        r_height = float(self.rect().height())
        t_height = float(metrics.height())

        if r_width > 0 and t_width > 0:
            h_factor = r_width / t_width

        if r_height > 0 and t_height > 0:
            v_factor = r_height / t_height

        if v_factor > 1.2 and h_factor > 1.2:
            return self.calculate_fit(mid, upper)
        elif v_factor < 1 and h_factor < 1:
            return self.calculate_fit(lower, mid)

        factor = min(h_factor, v_factor)

        if factor < 1 or factor > 1.3:
            new_size = int(mid * factor)
            if new_size % 2 != 0:
                new_size -= 1
            return new_size

        return mid

    def scale_text(self):  # resize text to fit within space
        h_factor = 1
        v_factor = 1

        r_width = float(self.rect().width())
        t_width = float(self.get_width())

        r_height = float(self.rect().height())
        t_height = float(self.font_metrics.height())

        if t_width > r_width and t_height > r_height:
            self.setFont(size=self.min_text_size)
            return

        if r_width > 0 and t_width > 0:
            h_factor = r_width / t_width

        if r_height > 0 and t_height > 0:
            v_factor = r_height / t_height

        factor = min(h_factor, v_factor)

        if factor < 1 or factor > 1.3:
            new_size = int(self.font.pointSize() * factor)
            if new_size % 2 != 0:
                new_size -= 1
            self.setFont(size=new_size)

    def resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox.resizeEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.scale_text()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tbl = TestTable()

    columns = [u"Column 1", u"Column 2", u"Column 3", u"Column 4"]
    rows = [u"Row 1", u"Row 2", u"Row 3", u"Row 4", u"Row 5", u"Row 6"]

    tbl.set_header_labels(columns, "horizontal")
    tbl.set_header_labels(rows, "vertical")

    tbl.set_box_column(0, "text", "False")
    tbl.set_box_column(1, "number", -1)
    tbl.set_box_column(2, "text", "True")
    tbl.set_box_column(3, "number", 1)

    tbl.show()
    tbl.scale_to_data()
    tbl.clamp_font_table()
    app.exec_()

main()
```